# Magento2: How to filter collection by created_time from custom table in admin grid

Tags: magento2

I need to filter custom table collection in admin grid. I'm struggling with this. 
Please suggest for this.

Here is my code

```
namespace Abc\Mkt\Model\ResourceModel\Logs;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection {
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
        'Abc\Mkt\Model\Logs',
        'Abc\Mkt\Model\ResourceModel\Logs'  );
    } 
}
```

di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="AbcMktGridFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
                <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="AbcMktGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Abc\Mkt\Model\ResourceModel\Logs\Collection</argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">AbcMktGridFilterPool</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="Abc\Mkt\Model\ResourceModel\Logs\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">abc_error_logs</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Abc\Mkt\Model\ResourceModel\Logs</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="grazitti_mkt_index_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Abc\Mkt\Model\ResourceModel\Logs\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Notification\MessageList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="messages" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="ExpiryAlert" xsi:type="string">Abc\Mkt\Model\System\Message\ExpiryAlert</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you created GRID using ui_component ?

Comment: yes, I have created

Comment: You want to sort that by asc/desc position or something else ?

Comment: I need records three days old from custom table

Comment: @Shiwani see my answer hope this will help you

Comment: @Waqar Ali  I have implemented this code but not working. Can you please check again?

Comment: @Shiwani i have tested this on my system can you show me your di.xml?

Comment: Updated my code

Comment: @Waqar Ali Can you please check my updated question?

Comment: @Shiwani see my updated answer

Comment: i am working on the same module and its working fine here

Comment: okay i will check updated code

Answer (score 0):

In Your

> Abc\Mkt\Model\ResourceModel\Logs\Collection.php

```
class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    protected $_idFieldName = 'entity_id';
    /**
     * Collection constructor
     *
     *
     * @param  EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory
     * @param  LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param  FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
     * @param  ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param  StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param  AdapterInterface $connection
     * @param  AbstractDb $resource
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        $this->_init(
            'Abc\Mkt\Model\Logs',
            'Abc\Mkt\Model\ResourceModel\Logs'
        );
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
    }
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        \\ timeOfLastThreeDays
        parent::_initSelect();
        $this->getSelect()->where('main_table.created_time BETWEEN ADDDATE(NOW(),-3) AND NOW() ');
    }
}
```

Here is `di.xml` Your can compare your One with mine

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="frontname_controller_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Module\Grid\Collection</item> <!-- Collection path -->
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Module\Grid\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">tablename</argument>
            <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_categoryimages_listing</argument>
            <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">vendor_grid_collection</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Module</argument>
        </arguments>
</type>
```